# How to solve the error: "UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter"

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm trying to call a UICollectionView (which is connected in one of my viewcontrollers) in a seperated Swift-file. Now I'm getting the error "UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter" and I don't know how to solve it. I'm getting the error at the line "let allImageCells = UICollectionView()". I already looked on the internet but I didn't find anything useful for my project. I hope someone can help me! Thank you in advance!

p.s. I'm quite sure that my code is very inefficient (and might not work too) but all I try to do is loading different folders (with images)in Firebase.

```
//
//  Wardrobe.swift
//  WhatToWear
//
//  Created by issd on 06/04/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 1. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

var dataIsLoaded = false
var allJackets = [outfitPart]()
var allSweaters = [outfitPart]()
var allTrousers = [outfitPart]()
var allShoes = [outfitPart]()

var jacketRef: DatabaseReference!
var sweaterRef: DatabaseReference!
var trousersRef: DatabaseReference!
var shoesRef: DatabaseReference!

let allImageCells = UICollectionView()
let wardrobeController = wardrobeViewController()

var allUploadedImages = [uploadedImages]()

func loadallOutfitParts() {
    wardrobeController.allImagesCollection = allImageCells

    jacketRef = Database.database().reference().child("jackets")
    loadJackets()

    sweaterRef = Database.database().reference().child("sweaters")
    loadSweaters()

    trousersRef = Database.database().reference().child("trousers")
    loadTrousers()

    shoesRef = Database.database().reference().child("shoes")
    loadShoes()

    //Load top outfitparts and store in outfitPartsTop
    //Load bottom outfitparts and store in outfitPartsBottom
    //Load shoe outfitparts and store in outfitPartsShoes

    dataIsLoaded = true
}

func loadJackets() {
    jacketRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var newImages = [uploadedImages]()
        for allUploadedImagesSnapshot in snapshot.children {
            let newImageObject = uploadedImages(snapshot: allUploadedImagesSnapshot as! DataSnapshot)
            newImages.append(newImageObject)
        }

        allUploadedImages = newImages
        wardrobeController.allImagesCollection.reloadData()
    })
}

func loadSweaters() {
    sweaterRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var newImages = [uploadedImages]()
        for allUploadedImagesSnapshot in snapshot.children {
            let newImageObject = uploadedImages(snapshot: allUploadedImagesSnapshot as! DataSnapshot)
            newImages.append(newImageObject)
        }

        allUploadedImages = newImages
        wardrobeController.allImagesCollection.reloadData()
    })
}

func loadTrousers() {
    trousersRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var newImages = [uploadedImages]()
        for allUploadedImagesSnapshot in snapshot.children {
            let newImageObject = uploadedImages(snapshot: allUploadedImagesSnapshot as! DataSnapshot)
            newImages.append(newImageObject)
        }

        allUploadedImages = newImages
        wardrobeController.allImagesCollection.reloadData()
    })
}

func loadShoes() {
    shoesRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var newImages = [uploadedImages]()
        for allUploadedImagesSnapshot in snapshot.children {
            let newImageObject = uploadedImages(snapshot: allUploadedImagesSnapshot as! DataSnapshot)
            newImages.append(newImageObject)
        }

        allUploadedImages = newImages
        wardrobeController.allImagesCollection.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: An advice for the future: Just search for the error message here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UICollectionView+must+be+initialized+with+a+non-nil+layout+parameter , there are more than 60 results.

Comment: I want to call the UICollectionView in a Swift-file, I'm not using a viewcontroller!

Comment: The solution is the same: You have to use the designated initializer. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618053-init)